# Cookie is sometimes lost with WebBrowser control

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, session-cookies

I added WebBrowser control to form X, it is used in rare cases to download a file. On form load I invoke

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "about:blank"
```

However sometimes my application session cookies are lost after form unload (and user gets a message to relogin). The problem is reproducible on some machines, and not consistent.

Is there a workaround or an explanation to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it uses Internet Explorer's settings.  One of those settings dictate that the cookies should not be maintained.

My suggestion would be to have your app handle knowledge of data, and simply pass it back to the web pages appropriately.

Or, if you have access to the web pages, make it so it uses an ID for session data instead of cookies.

For PHP:

```
<?php ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0'); ?>
```